# IE8 Expected Identifier

Tags: jquery

I am using a library isInViewport and I keep getting a error about `Expected identifier` for line 8.

https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport/blob/master/lib/isInViewport.js#L8

I am really confused why this is an issue as it is just

`$.fn.do`

I am also getting an error anytime I try and use `jQuery.do`

Any idea what is up?

Comment: What version of jquery do you have included?

Comment: I dropped the ball on that one didn't I? Sigh.   

It's fixed in [2.2.0](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) and is available on `bower` (`bower install isInViewport`).   

I have aliased `.do` with `.run`. `.do` remains available in browsers where it works but I would suggest you switch to `.run`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do` is a [reserved keyword](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords) in JavaScript. Actually, I'm surprised, that other browsers let it slip.

Comment: (ES5) Reserved words are actually only illegal as identifiers, not identifier names

Comment: True, and things like `foo['while']` are allowed. But with the issues around setting CSS `float` and `class` I thought, `$.fn.do` (not `$.fn['do']`) would cause issues, too. In any case, a thing like `{ do: 'foo' }` is not allowed without quoting the identifier.